# Does anyone knows what does mysql erro code ECONNREFUSED mean?

Tags: mysql, node.js

So I use nodejs, I have remote hosted mysql server. I also have user seted with % host, I can even login into mysql-workbench, but when i try to connect with node it throw this err on me:

```
 errno: -111,
 code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
```

my connection code looks like this:

```
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
})
```

I tried to search but even when I tried everything I could find it doesn't work.
As a server i use ubuntu 20.04
Anyone here know what to do?

Comment: "Connection refused" means the server wasn't running, wasn't where you thought it was, or was behind a misconfigured firewall. Double check that `process.env` contains the correct values.

Comment: @tadman I tried everything I can find user host = %, bind address is set to 0.0.0.0 and i don't know what more, and the .env is correct

Comment: You can't connect to the hostname `%`, you must connect to a valid DNS name or `localhost`.

Comment: @tadman it is more like -h ipOfServer -u user@%

Comment: The `%` is an artifact of how MySQL represents it internally, you do not specify that when connecting. User `user` connecting from a network address is tested against `user@%` internally. The username is *strictly* `user`.